# After deploying site to Heroku, can't connect to external API , but works locally (Node.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, heroku

My site performs a 'GET' request to an external API to retrieve data. It works locally. However after deploying my site to Heroku I can no longer connect to the external API to retrieve data. I'm receiving a 503 service unavailable error.

I'm currently using the 'GOT' npm module for the http-request and I've tried a couple different modules that all work locally but not through heroku.
I think it might be a header issue but I can't pinpoint what might be wrong. Can someone guide me to what the issue might be? Thanks.

Server-side function I created to make the GET request

```
var fetchApiData = function(targetSeason, targetCategory, callback) {
  let options = {
    headers: {
      'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.111 Safari/537.36',
      'Accept-Encoding': '*',
      'Accept-Language': ('en'),
      'origin': ('https://apidomain.nba.com')
     }
   };

  (async () => {
    try {
      const response = await got(('https://apidomain.nba.com/stats/leagueleaders/?LeagueID=00&PerMode=PerGame&StatCategory=' + targetCategory + '&Season=' + targetSeason + '&SeasonType=Regular%20Season&Scope=S', options);
      callback(null, JSON.parse(response.body));      
    } catch (error) {
      callback(error.response.body, null);
    }
  })();
};
```

Error in Browser

```
POST https://myserver.herokuapp.com/player-data 503 (Service Unavailable)
Axios Error....... Error: Request failed with status code 503
at createError (createError.js?f777:16)
at settle (settle.js?199f:18)
at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (xhr.js?14ed:77)
```

Error from Heroku Log

```
2018-05-09T22:14:35.153304+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=POST path="/player-data" host=myserver.herokuapp.com request_id=18a37de9-9f85-4c03-a038-bf0f90223e1e fwd="64.134.226.170" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=30001ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
```

Comment: The error clearly states that it's getting a timeout. This may help you out: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/request-timeout

Comment: @HarshitPrasad Thanks for the resource link. I see it's getting a timeout, however, I'm not sure what's causing it. When run locally, the request takes about 700ms. But on Heroku the request is hitting the 30 second timeout limit. One of Heroku's solutions through the docs you provided is to create a background process. But even if this worked I believe in theory the request would still be taking longer than 30 seconds and I definitely need it under 800 ms.

Comment: on the free-tier, Heroku can be constrained and slower than you would think .. if you need an async worker then see this : https://github.com/heroku/devcenter-java-web-worker   you can also upgrade your heroku setup - memory cpu -

Comment: Independently check each resource axios may be connecting to; make sure they're all working fine. This was the case with my Heroku deploy... the app was fine... it was one of the API servers that had an issue. From a high-level, this means my app needs better error handling for when an API server is unavailable.